# Cannot run SOQL on Encrypted Contact Field - Deterministic Encryption Enabled

Tags: soql, platform-encryption

I have shield encryption enabled on the contact object and on the email field of the contact object.

In custom apex code (a inbound email handler specifically), I am trying to run a SOQL query to see the contact exists, if not, create it.

I am unable to run the following query `select id from contact where email =: email.fromAddress` as I receive the following error:

```
select id from contact where email =: email.fromAddress
                             ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:30
field 'email' can not be filtered in a query call
```

I enabled deterministic encryption, but I still receive the error.

Are they any additional steps I need to take to be able to run SOQL on the contact email field?

Related Docs: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_pe_deterministic.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must also generate a new tenant secret under the choose tenant secret type (Data in Salesforce (Deterministic).

[image]

At that point, you can then go back to the encryption policy, click encrypt fields, and change the encryption scheme for that specific field to deterministic.